# How to make this Tkinter and OpenCV program more scalable?

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I have this part of my program to show webcam feed on a Tkinter window:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = Tk()

def show_frames():
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    label.imgtk = imgtk
    label.configure(image=imgtk)
    label.after(20, show_frames)


label = Label(root)
label.grid()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

show_frames()
root.mainloop()
```

Whole program is getting quite long and hard to naivgate and I am trying get split the source code in multiple files. However I have trouble even with this core part of my code. I tried giving `show_frames()` argument cap, and it runs the function once and breaks on the seccond frame.

Then I tried this:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = Tk()

def show_frames():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    label.imgtk = imgtk
    label.configure(image=imgtk)
    label.after(20, show_frames)

label = Label(root)
label.grid()

show_frames()
root.mainloop()
```

In this one I am unsure how to "load" the frame onto screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` outside of `show_frames` function.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import cv2

root = Tk()

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

def show_frames():
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(cap.read()[1], cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    label.imgtk = imgtk
    label.configure(image=imgtk)
    label.after(20, show_frames)

label = Label(root)
label.grid()

show_frames()
root.mainloop()
```

Also, don't use the wildcard `*` it may cause you problems in the future.

Comment: Is this really different from the`first code that I put in? I understand that `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` is before defining the the funktion, but I don't understand how that makes it different?